# Recursive SQL Query with Defined Start Point

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, recursive-query

I'm trying to get a recursive query to work with a defined starting point.

Here's some sample data from my table called `Part_v_Container`:

```
Serial_No   From_Container  Part_Key    Part_Operation_Key
1234                1233    5678         5
1233                1232    5678         4
1231                1230    5678         3
1230                NULL    5678         2
```

Basically we ship a serial number and then I need to trace it back following all the previous serial numbers `From_Container` through the process.  In my real query I'll have the starting `Serial_No` be a user defined variable.

Here's my attempt:

```
;WITH Recursive_cte AS
(SELECT 
  PContainer.Serial_No
  ,PContainer.From_Container
  ,PContainer.Part_Key
  ,PContainer.Part_Operation_Key

  FROM Part_v_Container AS PContainer
  WHERE Serial_No LIKE '1234'  -- Will be user defined variable

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    PContainer.Serial_No
    ,PContainer.From_Container
    ,PContainer.Part_Key
    ,PContainer.Part_Operation_Key  
  FROM Recursive_cte
  INNER JOIN
  Part_v_Container AS PContainer
  ON PContainer.From_Container = Recursive_cte.Serial_No 
  )

 SELECT * 
 FROM Recursive_cte
```

Yet this only returns one row, the `Serial_No` = `1234` row.  My real data set has thousands of serial numbers and I need to be able to pick which ones I pick from to trace back, not a broad query that is recursive for every one in my table.

I've tried reading several articles and examples to get this to work, including the one [here](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/) with no success.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Given your sample data and your input of `serial_no like '1234'` how many rows did you anticipate you should get back? If the answer is two, then your Recursive Member's ON should be `PContainer.Serial_No = Recursuve_cte.From_Container`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question. Please post your desired results for the sample data to help clarify.

Comment: What is your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the join fields inverted.

**[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4d95d/3)**

```
;WITH Recursive_cte AS (
  SELECT 
    PContainer.Serial_No
  , PContainer.From_Container
  , PContainer.Part_Key
  , PContainer.Part_Operation_Key

  FROM Part_v_Container AS PContainer
  WHERE Serial_No = 1234  -- Will be user defined variable

UNION ALL

  SELECT 
      PContainer.Serial_No
    , PContainer.From_Container
    , PContainer.Part_Key
    , PContainer.Part_Operation_Key  
  FROM Recursive_cte
  INNER JOIN  Part_v_Container AS PContainer
     ON Recursive_cte.From_Container = PContainer.Serial_No 
)

SELECT * 
FROM Recursive_cte
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Serial_No | From_Container | Part_Key | Part_Operation_Key |
|-----------|----------------|----------|--------------------|
|      1234 |           1233 |     5678 |                  5 |
|      1233 |           1232 |     5678 |                  4 |
```